# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with this code the error is below the code and that's the code . Please help me to resolve.

```
# Import requiements
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Create our class
class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/Users/dragos/Downloads/geckodriver')   

    # Function will log us in to Instagram
    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        # Navigate to the Instagram login page
        bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
        time.sleep(3)

        # Find the email and password boxes, enter our login credentials
        email = bot.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        password = bot.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)

        # Wait for 1 second then press ENTER
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        # Wait 3 second while the post-login page loads
        time.sleep(3)

    def findMyFollowers(self, number_of_followers):
        bot = self.bot

        bot.get('https://instagram.com/' + self.username)
        time.sleep(2)

        bot.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/' + self.username + '/followers/"]').click()

        time.sleep(1)

        popup = bot.find_element_by_class_name('isgrP')

        followers_array = []

        i = 1

        while len(followers_array) <= number_of_followers:
            bot.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', popup)
            time.sleep(0.4)

            followers = bot.find_elements_by_class_name('FPmhX')

            for follower in followers:
                if follower not in followers_array:
                    followers_array.append(follower.text)

            i+=1

        print(followers_array)

        self.followers = followers_array

    def followTheirFollowers(self, number_to_follow):
        bot = self.bot

        for follower in self.followers:
            bot.get('https://instagram.com/' + follower)
            time.sleep(2)

            if(len(bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'This Account is Private')]")) > 0):
                # If they're private, we can't see their follower list, so skip them
                continue

            bot.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/' + follower + '/followers/"]').click()
            time.sleep(3)

            follow = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Follow')]")

            i = 1

            for follower in follow:
                if(i != 1):
                    bot.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", follower)

                if(i > number_to_follow):
                    break

                i+=1

            time.sleep(2)


insta = InstagramBot('Username(here I put my username)', 'Password(and here password)')
insta.login()
insta.findMyFollowers(5)
insta.followTheirFollowers(10)
```

And here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dragos/Desktop/follow.py", line 93, in <module>
    insta = InstagramBot('y', 'x')
  File "/Users/dragos/Desktop/follow.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/Users/dragos/Downloads/geckodriver')   
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
```

And I don't know how to resolve and I need this for my class I need this very fast please. if you want more details please say what you want to sand please
I run this code using python launcher and when is start up Firefox I have this error and idk how to resolve